# Create a generic Factory class

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-generics

I have a couple of Factory classes that do the same:

```
export class XFactory {
  private readonly validator: XValidator;
  private readonly transformer: XTransformer;

  private constructor( private readonly data: any, connection: Connection) {
    this.validator = new XValidator(connection);
    this.transformer = new XTransformer();
  }

  public static async build(data: any, connection: Connection) {
    const factory = new XFactory (connection);

    await factory.validate();

    const dto = await factory.transform();
    const x = new X(dto, connection);

    return x;
  }

  private async validate(): Promise<void | never> {
    await this.validator.validate(this.data);
  }

  private async transform(): Promise<XDto> {
    return await this.transformer.transform(this.data);
  }
}
```

The process is always the same:

1. Validate data, throwing an error if not valid
2. Transforming the data into a valid DTO consumed by a constructor
3. Instantiating the object and return it

I'm having problems creating an abstraction of this class:

I have tried with a parent Factory like this, but i have two problems, marked with an asterisk:

```
export class Factory<T,U> {
  private constructor( 
    private readonly data: any,
    private readonly validator: Validator,
    private readonly transformer: Transformer<U>
    ) {}

  protected static 
  public static async build(data: any, validator: Validator, transformer: Transformer<U>*1, connection: Connection) {
    const factory = new Factory (data, validator, transformer);

    await factory.validate();

    const dto: U*1 = await factory.transform();
    const x: T*1 = new T*2(...[dto, connection]);

    return x;
  }

  private async validate(): Promise<void|never> {
    await this.validator.validate(this.data);
  }

  private async transform(): Promise<XDto> {
    return await this.transformer.transform(this.data);
  }
}
```

*1 Static members cannot reference class type parameters: this is a minor problem, but I'd love to know a workaround for this.
*2 Cannot find name 'T': Is there a way to instantiate this class? I know typescript is uncapable of translating this to js, i just tried to write something that make my intentions clear.

Also the constructor method is private because I don't want to separate validation and transformation from the constructor, but they have an asyncronous nature.

¿Is there another approach to solve this problem or can my code be modified so I can refactor those XFactory classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *1 Static members cannot reference class type parameters.

This is like asking a printing press who its author is. The press printed many books, all of which have different authors. The request doesn't make sense.

The class type parameters are per instance. A different instance may have different type parameters. And static methods have no intrinsic relationship with the class they are on other than convention. It's just a namespace to group related functionality. And only by convention do those functions do tasks that are related to the instances.

---

I think what you want here is for the static `build` method to be generic, so it can create a `Factory` instance with the correct types. Then you can simply use that instance.

```
// Make up some types to support what follows.
type Validator<Data> = { validate(data: Data): Promise<boolean> }
type Transformer<Data, Dto> = { transform(data: Data): Dto }
type Connection = { isConnected: boolean }

export class Factory<Data, Dto> {
    private constructor( 
        private readonly data: Data,
        private readonly validator: Validator<Data>,
        private readonly transformer: Transformer<Data, Dto>
    ) {}

    public static async build<Data, Dto, DtoInstance>(
        data: Data,
        validator: Validator<Data>,
        transformer: Transformer<Data, Dto>,
        dtoConstructor: new (dto: Dto, connection: Connection) => DtoInstance,
        connection: Connection
    ): Promise<DtoInstance> {
        const factory = new Factory(data, validator, transformer);
        await factory.validate();
        const dto = await factory.transform();
        return new dtoConstructor(dto, connection);
    }

    private async validate(): Promise<void|never> {
        await this.validator.validate(this.data);
    }

    private async transform(): Promise<Dto> {
        return await this.transformer.transform(this.data);
    }
}
```

I've renamed `T` and `U` here to `Data` and `Dto`, respectively. `Data` is the input format, and `Dto` is the output of the transform.

Now note how the `build` function is also generic. It accepts its own generic type parameters (I've used the same names, but they are totally disconnected). This allows the arguments to the `Factory` constructor to be specifically typed when `build()` is called, which then sets the types of the instance.

Lastly, `build()` also accepts a constructor, which will take the transform's output and return an instance of something. That instance type we capture as a generic from the constructor to set the return type.

Now to test it:

```
// mock a connection
const connection = { isConnected: true }

class TestDto {
    public finalNum: number
    constructor(data: { finalNum: number }, connection: Connection) {
        this.finalNum = data.finalNum
    }
}

async function test() {
    const testDto = await Factory.build(
        { srcNum: 123 },
        { validate: async (data) => data.srcNum > 0 },
        { transform: (data) => ({ finalNum: data.srcNum }) },
        TestDto,
        connection
    )
    console.log(testDto) // TestDto: { finalNum: 123 }
    console.log(testDto.finalNum) // 123
}

test()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=1&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=57&ssc=7&pln=35&pc=1#code/PTAEFkEMGsFNQK4AdQGcD2BbeAXAnkrKqDumskugE46gDuAFpLQGboA276dqAdALAAofIVAA1SOwCWAE2bUAPABFmkAHygAvKADeoAG6TZzWAAo5OSAC5QKywEobABSpYpqWAoBG6DrEgAdhoAvkIi8AAqVIGobFTYVMqqADS2pBraejjRAbHUmOaqNnaQjmlkocIE8ADC6AEBsADGOFL1Wrqg7nUNzTiwMjY+foGglUKwAB6UNKBN7JCoxABikC3UeEmWqUrpukKgh6BIVFKG-XP1qNkI61SmoAdHzydnJqBU-jL17HigFtZbCkns9Dq9zvBPpBvgFfgYjBZqDYJNJEYkSmpkiDQeD3lCYXDsjE4gkbFFiflYOiUuU1Nj7LpxoIXggvNImmhLK0OYs8AEOV4EFJ2DItpAdqQJegAJK5Sz82BqUzY54A4rA5mgw6GVHyKjIhF6sWYlVHIm5ElUsk5PLxKliqUmzVamSkHrXKi3Uj60CNOigcykYqSy69FptAI2HqNcP1BmaDS7GVywJNWBY52gpr1GOtepRnN9CP05yuTDuTxJ2XXVOK-aZ57ZuWgFhrb1-bR+0CrO54QrbeG672pc22hL2ADcpsOkDokCkrDbG14OuM-VMk+noeu-1IHVn88Xvd4o5JG6nDaOnxwCCoAV9sH9rvQ7pud0D6FSTdzEc3maZLynBCoC8vyg5rmYZQuG4HgKPo6CyAAPo0+hUhoOhbgeC4kAw7groa3r4UOZg4LhfAAn+zwAUcuIXKBHKnvkG6ljBlZ7Bhl6HNet73lhtCkXhjF2lQJ42meAnkaolFHJUTIgKAmDoE00AgaGP71EITY7t+RbtJkXSoNGfQDDYNzwEy8yLMQEREDgSb1iybJSByLBSAEkgAHIIJgNgBN5XhUtiWlvt6-aAnornuewXk+b6-lUmMX6FrGkagEZKUMhxWqHBJvCRZ53kdACeVuQVmDYrJQhCPRLYIPyeb3v01wbg5RzBSQtn2dofHdkuVB4LwgrCjIyqcZ0qBUE0MU2AAjAATAAzIlW56KuFiwDYNVhfGGjFRNU2FRoAAMy1jVkYn5DY21aBopgRaV0XeTYe2TTFYwMsEGbZaANnXEmX3ZTpKX0kFVx+LwXAAOamE1dmkAy8m-XD6A2PdUXTaA81LZUjZg+wsAQ+g0Ow0mJXo95CNgFjQhMrDG5AA)

---

All that said... why are you using a class here at all? This would be *far* simpler if it was a pure function. The implementation is 3 short lines.

```
async function build<Data, Dto, DtoInstance>({
    data,
    validate,
    transform,
    dtoConstructor,
    connection
}: {
    data: Data,
    validate: (data: Data) => Promise<void>,
    transform: (data: Data) => Dto,
    dtoConstructor: new (dto: Dto, connection: Connection) => DtoInstance,
    connection: Connection,
}): Promise<DtoInstance> {
    await validate(data);
    const dto = transform(data);
    return new dtoConstructor(dto, connection);
}
```

Which you would use like so:

```
// Make a reusable function bound to a specific Dto.
// Or maybe add as a static method of `TestDto`, `TestDto.build()`?
async function buildTestDto(data: { srcNum: number }) {
    return await build({
        data,
        validate: async (data) => {
            if (data.srcNum < 0) throw new Error("value must be positive")
        },
        transform: (data) => ({ finalNum: data.srcNum }),
        dtoConstructor: TestDto,
        connection,
    })
}

async function go() {
    const testDto = await buildTestDto({ srcNum: 123 })
    console.log(testDto) // TestDto: { finalNum: 123 }
    console.log(testDto.finalNum) // 123

    const invalid = await buildTestDto({ srcNum: -456 }) // throws
    console.log(invalid)
}
go()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=1&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=32&ssc=49&pln=32&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwRAxsAloqBeKBvKdAZ3iVWAgBMAuKAIzjgBsIBDBKAXwFgAoP1kRAIUUAGYBXERix0J6JpQA8AEVbBWAGigrgcbbrgBJBEQ0iIAPgAUePlAdRK6rfccA3Vk3TOKmtw7AAE7sRGJwQQC2-ryOTnqkZkESaBExcSiIyGiYCHyctHaxjr6stGoa6R5ePuoQtNal5S4AlDiWUAAKQXCRxBBK7nA+llWBIabhUQ1NOq3tOnpj8XCJwSl6QbTIAO5QjXrlS1CZZDmItKTZMght2B2GJmbsKBDLp9e5l1nkuTGcLVo3V6-VUeie5leHSKcVYO1Y6GAUE83l8EEarQA3AETogzCscFBgqEppEMRoWtjig4ghBgBIghxdis1slUkEDvpcWcbpT8nw+AB6QVQSJwFAAaygrG5n0QfFO+I+vywuAIxCu5CotHW0B4-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-TSq2UhLkv1DI0pYTLstykq5wqktCpFaqBW8wNCAQdDh0CmCQvg8KPIIcjouUgBaAAWABWAA2UCoCKhi4B2IhUtMdLGpyl0Bqk3h9XczygA)

Comment: This is a great answer. I feel a lot of code could be simpler once people with a heavy OOP background realize that most things are easier as functions.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I didn't even know you could use generics on functions. You taught me a lot here. And to answer your question about why did I choose the OOP approach is that the project I'm working on is OO, I didn't even consider a functional solution when I stumbled upon this problem.